# I need to reference a method from another page

Tags: c#, sql, methods

I have a method in on page/tab of this project i am doing, here is the first piece of code:

```
    public void SomeMethod(string copyid)
    {
        var con = Conn.ConnString();

        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(con))
        {
            string oString = "Select  * from ACCOUNTS where COPYID =@copyid";
            SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString, myConnection);
            oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@copyid", copyid);
            myConnection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (oReader.HasRows)
                {
                    string value = string.Empty;
                    while (oReader.Read())
                    {
                        value = oReader["FNAME"].ToString();
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(value);
                }

            }
        }
    }  

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SomeMethod(txtCopyPin.Text);
```

^That is where i reference the method in the click event of the login button

So basically the user get's to the login screen and has to enter a pin into the textbox, i check if that pin is in the SQL database under the COPYID field, just to test it when you login i made a messagebox with the name associated with that pin which i also get from the database, this all works, now what i need to do is use that name in the next page, the "home page", i want that name so show up in  label, but it's in a complete diffrent page so I don't know how to call the method.

Answer (score 0):

add this *SomeMethod* in a class under an additional project (Class Library) that you can use as repository for all the methods/function you need to invoke in your pages.

Answer (score 0):

use a session, no need to make a database call again

after you fetch the name set it to a session variable like this

```
Session["Name"] = value;
```

in your SomeMethod function

then access this session in your next page

```
lbl.text = Convert.ToString(Session["Name"]);
```

Side note: hope this is web form and not win forms